# Spring session generates session even though I am not authorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, spring-session

I have created an application which uses `spring session`. When I make a call to api which needs to be authenticated I am getting an error, which is fine but also application generates a session id. Is it a correct behaviour?

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
set-cookie: SESSION=SESSION_ID; Path=/; HttpOnly
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 17:04:46 GMT
connection: close
```

My authorization method looks which is called after log in:

```
public void authorize(final String authorizationCode, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("Logging...");
        final HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
    httpSession.setAttribute("token", token);
    httpSession.setAttribute("account_id", accountId);
    httpSession.setAttribute("user_id", userId);
    }
```

What is more in `application.properties` I set `server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true` and still in cookie is only `httpOnly`.

Comment: Session with the client does not equals a set up security and authentication context.

Comment: Ok so how can I implement in a way to work with above case?

Comment: Unfortunately in order to spring session documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/ all examples do same things as me - get the session from the request

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. Could you please rephrase the question? Otherwise it seems you already answered it, that it is the correct behavior.

Comment: I would like to have a spring session with httpOnly and secure flag to be available when the session is set. And I'd like to know why I receive 401 when trying to hit my api even though the session is created.

Comment: Well, you need to configure spring security, I'd advise reading around this part: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests

Comment: I already did it

Comment: Then show us your security config. Maybe we can spot something